# How to call this member template function?

Tags: c++

What is the correct way to call this function?

```
template<typename T, typename U>
DX& DataExchange::AddNew(const T& Table, const U& (T::* fnMemoryFunc)() const)
```

Comment: second argument is a pointer on method.

Comment: That is just a function signature. No way to tell what the function would do. Presumably it takes a const reference to a table of type T and a const member function pointer from type T that takes no arguments and returns a const U reference.

Comment: I know the second argument is a function, but is that a method of the same object? Yes, this is just a signature, my question was badly phased, I will figure it out for myself what does it do, but I can't write a line that calls the function.

Comment: Depends on what `DataExchange` is, and what is this `Table` concept it expects.

Comment: The function needs an object of any class and a pointer to a method of the supplied object, which it may call later. This was the answer I was looking for, sorry for the bad wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way is to call the function is:

```
struct Foo {
    const X& fnMemoryFunc() const { return /*what ever*/};
};
int main (){
    Foo a;
    AddNew(a, &Foo::fnMemoryFunc)
}
```

I change AddNew to free function per simplicity.

EDIT: as looks in comments that you asked what it may do... this is all suppositions... and not enough info.

AddNew needs a reference to probably a internal data of class T (cons reference return type.), that could be any type  and thats the reason because the pointer to the method is required, to know the return type.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! Unfortunately I got downvoted because of the bad wording of my question. One thing I don't get is why the function has 2 consts.

Comment: @KillerZefi they are there to match the method signature.
The fnMemoryFunc() method will has to const, const X& to said that it will return a constant reference to element X <to enforce no changes on the internal state from outside of Foo class>
The 2nd const on nfMemoryFunc() const is to told the compiler that this method should not change any internal attribute of Foo.